# missing text by read(1024)

Tags: python

I have a txt file and I am reading and print it.

### code:

```
f=open('e://send.txt','r',encoding='UTF-8')
for i in f:
    text=f.read(1024)
    print(text+'\n\n\n')

f.close()`
```

when text print some lines are missing. for exp :
txt file is:

```
 کشاورزی مینوشت را بنویسد! از نظر شما شاید این دو برنامه نویس هر دو

 ***یکسان باشند اما اتفاقی که می افتد این است که بازار ثابت نمی ماند!***
    
فرض کنید به خاطر توافق
```

but out put is:

```
 بنویسد! از نظر شما شاید این دو برنامه نویس هر دو 
 missing lines
فرض کنید به خاطر توافق
```

Comment: With `for i in f`, `i` is a line of the file. You don't need to do `f.read(1024)`. Or if you do you also need to `print(i)`.

Comment: I need a loop and in every time send 1024 of file. beacuse I cant send more or less. Do you have better solution for remove 'i'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either read the file line-by-line:

```
for i in f:
    print(i)
```

or read it in chunks:

```
while True:
    text = f.read(1024)
    if not text:
        break
    print(text, eol='')
```

but don't do both. In your code, the text read into `i` by the `for` loop is ignored, and that's the data you are missing.

Answer (score 1):

`for i in f` will iterate over the lines of the file, and `read()` will read from it. With both your iteration and your reading moving the file position forward, you'll end up missing some data.

Try choosing one or the other here. `read()` will return an empty string on EOF, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually single loop reads from file twice, first iterator syntax (implicitly), second your read call. If you are using `for line in file` idiom, skip your explicit `read()`.

```
with open('e:\\send.txt','r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

Comment: yes you are right! but I need a loop and in every time send 1024 of file. beacuse I cant send more or less.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, using a text file-like in for loop reads it line by line, but for-loops are pretty and pythonic, so one thing that I've done in the past (if I need to do this chunked reading more than once) is pop it into a generator function to keep things clean.

Something like:

```
def chunked(f, chunk_size=1024):
    while True:
        chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
        if not chunk:
            break
        yield chunk
```

Which you'd call in your code like:

```
f = open('e://send.txt','r',encoding='UTF-8')
for text in chunked(f):
    print(text + '\n\n\n')
```

It's basically the code that chepner suggested, just might keep the body of the code cleaner?